# Using std::stringstream in std::exception.what()

Tags: c++, exception, buffer, stringstream

Wanting to implement the std::exception class and especially the what function, I encountered a problem with std::stringstream.

To make it short, it's printing an empty string when I use this implementation:

```
const char *what() const throw () {
   std::stringstream ss;

   ss << "Error";
   if (_line > -1)
      ss << " at line " << std::to_string(_line);

   ss << ": " << _msg;

   return ss.str().c_str();
}
```

and printing something (eg: "Error at line 3") when I use this implementation:

```
const char *what() const throw () {
   std::stringstream ss;

   ss << "Error";
   if (_line > -1)
      ss << " at line " << std::to_string(_line);

   //ss << ": " << _msg; // COMMENT THIS LINE

   return ss.str().c_str();
}
```

I then even try to see if it comes from the ": " or from the variable _msg (std::string) but none of them seem to have influence.

Is this a buffer problem from the stringstream side or is it a manipulation problem from my side ? If it's a manipulation problem please explain me how to use it.

Comment: Please don't use the dynamic exception specification `throw()`. It has been deprecated since C++11 and will be removed in C++20. Use `noexcept` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ss.str().c_str();`

`str()` does this:

> Returns a copy of the underlying string [..]
>
> [(Source)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str)

So you now have a temporary `std::string`, on which you call `c_str()`. This returns a pointer to the (C) string *managed* by that temporary `std::string`.

So as soon as this statement is over (in this case when the function returns) the temporary `std::string` will be destructed which will delete / free the memory where that pointer you got from `c_str()` points to.

So you have an invalid pointer, accessing it is undefined behavior.

Solutions:

1. Make a copy of the C string, and return that.  **Bad** because now the caller has to free this copy, and this is not part of the "API" of [`std::exception::what()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what)
2. Add a `std::string` member to your class, fill *that* with the return value of `str()` (preferably in the constructor of the class ...) and return that members internal C string:

   ```cpp
   struct my_exception : public std::exception {
     std::string description;
     my_exception() {
       std::stringstream ss;
       // code to fill ss
       description = ss.str();
     }
     char const * what() const override {
       return description.c_str();
     }
   };
   ```

---

Preserving important comment from walnut:

> You need to be careful with this though. `std::string` may throw when copied and if that happens e.g. with an exception handler catching by copy, `std::terminate` will be called and the program will abort. On the other hand it will probably only throw when memory allocation fails which might be an error that you consider unrecoverable anyway (or not).

Comment: I need to admit it that I didn't like that line but I didn't know that, thank you. How would you then do something similar but keep the pointer valid ? and why does it work with the commented line ?

Comment: You need to be careful with this though. `std::string` may throw when copied and if that happens e.g. with an exception handler catching by copy, `std::terminate` will be called and the program will abort. On the other hand it will probably only throw when memory allocation fails which might be an error that you consider unrecoverable anyway (or not).

Comment: @walnut Thanks, that's an important point to consider. Added to the answer (comments sometimes disappear)

Comment: @DanielJour  You need to return `const char* `  in override function what()

Answer (score 1):

The [`str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) function returns a string by value. When you use it as you do that value will be temporary and the string object will be destructed immediately once the expression (`ss.str().c_str()`) ends.

That the temporary object is destructed means that the pointer you return will become invalid immediately.

One possible solution is to store the string in the exception object, and hope the pointer will not be used after the exception have been destructed.